# What is the best practice to update the Original Estimate in Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I would like to get few clarification of Original Estimate Field in JIRA.

I have started my work with 5d original estimate.
After completion of second day, I have logged 2d of work.

```
Current:
Original Estimate: 5d
Remaining Estimate: 3d
Logged: 2d
```

If I want to update my original estimate to 6d, whether I need update
Original Estimate field & Remaining field

Or updating Original Estimate field itself fine?

Will updating Original Estimate in the middle of work affect any other fields?

Helps much Appreciated.

Comment: you can update both fields original and remaining estimates as long as your project manager is fine. please refer https://mobikon.atlassian.net/secure/ShowTimeTrackingHelp.jspa?decorator=popup#TimeTracking

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best practice to update the Original Estimate in Jira?

To not.

The point of the original estimate is record how much time the team thought the ticket would take before work was started. That way the actual time can be compared to the original estimate and the information can be used so the team can get better at estimating.

If the estimate changes, then reflect that in the Remaining Estimate field. It is there to highlight how much more time you think is needed.